# how to use true value of a character in vimwiki ?

Tags: vim, escaping

I typed these content in vimwiki :

`here $1 is matched for[[name]]`

and then I convert wiki to HTML :

`here \)1 is matched for <a href="">name</a>`

The question is how to get **true value** of specail character ,such as `$`, `[[` ?

in Regexp , I can use backslash to use tre value of a character :
`here \$1 ....`

But in vimwiki , how can I do it ?